# javascript запрет ввода

Tags: javascript, html

Есть код, он не допускает ввод любых символов, кроме как натуральных чисел.

```
<html> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function check_field(id) { 
var field = document.getElementById(id); 
if (isNaN(field.value)) { 
alert('Помилка! Не дійсне число') 
} 
} 
</script> 
</head> 
<body> 
<form> 
Введіть дійсне число: 
<input type="text" id="t_field" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/\.(?=.*\.)|[^\d\.eE-]/g, '');"> 
<input type="button" value="Перевірити" onclick="check_field('t_field');"/> 
</form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Хочу узнать как работает эта строчка, позаимствованная из другого кода

```
<input type="text" id="t_field" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/\.(?=.*\.)|[^\d\.eE-]/g, '');">
```

Comment: Эм... При вводе очередного знака вырезает все символы **не** являющиеся частью числа?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Событие onkeyup возникает в момент отпускания нажатой клавиши. см. http://htmlbook.ru/html/attr/onkeyup

1. Внутри можно указывать как функцию, так и сам js
2. `this` - это текущий js-объект для доступа к полю ввода
3. `this.value` - введённое пользователем значение
4. `this.value.replace` - поиск и замена в значении чего угодно. см. https://javascript.ru/string/replace

В данной ситуации - всё, что попадает под регулярное выражение `\.(?=.*\.)|[^\d\.eE-]` будет заменено на пустую строку (т.е. удалено) после пользовательского ввода

Answer (score 1):

Регулярное выражение `(/\.(?=.*\.)|[^\d\.eE-]/g` отрезает все знаки которые не являются частью указанного числа. Почитай про регулярные выражения и расширь возможности ввода.